# How to get blob name from BlobResult[]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, blob, azure-storage

I would like to delete all files in my azure blob storage. In order to do so, I list all of blobs in my storage using *listBlobsSegmented()* and then pass the results into *deleteBlobIfExists()*. But the argument blob.name from *list BlobsSegment()* isn't correctly assigned. How to get blob name properly?

This is storage model:

```
const blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accessKey, host); 
const containerName = 'container';

module.exports.listAll = () => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        blobService.listBlobsSegmented(containerName, null, function(err, listBlobsResult) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(listBlobsResult);
            }
        });
    });
}

module.exports.delete = (blobName) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        blobService.deleteBlobIfExists(containerName, blobName, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve({ message: `Block blob '${blobName}' deleted` });
            }
        })
    })
}
```

This is how i use them:

```
const azureStorage = require('./storage-model')

router.get('/listAll', function(req, res) {
    azureStorage.listAll().then((listBlobsResult) => {
        console.log(listBlobsResult);
        res.send(listBlobsResult);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
});

router.get('/deleteAll', function(req, res) {
    azureStorage.listAll().then((listBlobsResult) => {
        var responseBody;
        for (blob in listBlobsResult.entries) {
            azureStorage.delete(blob.name).then((result) => {
                console.log(result);
                responseBody += result;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
        res.send(responseBody);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
})
```

After did so, it gave me error message

> ArgumentNullError: Required argument blob for function
>   deleteBlobIfExists is not defined

Here are some references from Microsoft
[`deleteBlobIfExists()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice?view=azure-node-latest#deleteblobifexists-string--string--errororresult-boolean--)
[`listBlobsSegmented()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice?view=azure-node-latest#listblobssegmented-string--continuationtoken--errororresult-listblobsresult--)
[ListBlobsResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice.listblobsresult?view=azure-node-latest#entries)
[BlobResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice.blobresult?view=azure-node-latest#name)

I found out that blob.name only returns blob index number, but not the actual blob name. Is there any one can help me? Thanks!

---

This is what **listBlobsResult.entries** looks like:

```
[ {previous blob result},
 BlobResult {
    name: 'my_container/some_picture.jpg',
    creationTime: 'Thu, 11 Jul 2019 09:33:20 GMT',
    lastModified: 'Thu, 11 Jul 2019 09:33:20 GMT',
    etag: '0x8D705A4CFCB5528',
    contentLength: '6300930',
    contentSettings:
     { contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
       contentEncoding: '',
       contentLanguage: '',
       contentMD5: 'OyHfg8c3irniQzyhtCBdrw==',
       cacheControl: '',
       contentDisposition: '' },
    blobType: 'BlockBlob',
    lease: { status: 'unlocked', state: 'available' },
    serverEncrypted: 'true' },
 {next blob result},
 ...{many others blob result}]
```

What I expect is that I can get blob name from entry blob in iteration over listBlobsResult.entries by using **blob.name**. But it gave me index of iteration.

Comment: If you want to delete all blobs, why don’t you simply delete the blob container?

Comment: Have you tried `listBlobs()` instead of  `listBlobsSegmented()` ?

Comment: @GauravMantri Beacuase I would like to keep the container. But maybe delete the container first than use **createContainerIfNotExists()** will be nice backup plan thanks!

Comment: @Neverever I ensure that listBlobsResult from both **listBlobs()** and **listBlobsSegmented()** are correct. I'll edit the question to expose listBlobsResult later. By the way, **listBlobs()** seems to be implement only in older SDK, but not newer SDK, and I'm using the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listBlobsResult.entries` is of type `BlobResult[]`

And, there are two types of `for` loop, and it is very common that people mixed them up.

**for ... in**

```
for (let index in listBlobsResult.entries) {
    let blob = listBlobsResult.entries[index];

    /* ... do the work */
}
```

**for ... of**

```
for (let blob of listBlobsResult.entries) {
    /* ... do the work */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code.

1. The `for...in` statement in your callback function of `router.get('/deleteAll', callback)`. According to the MDN document [`for...in statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement), the `blob` variable of `for (blob in listBlobsResult.entries)` acutally is the numberic index for the array `listBlobsResult.entries` as you said, please see the figure below.

   [image]

   So to fix it, there are two solutions.

   1.1. To use [`for...of statement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement) instead of `for...in statement`, so just change the key word `in` to `of` without other changes, then the `blob` variable is the `BlobResult` object.

   ```
   for (var blob of listBlobsResult.entries) {
       azureStorage.delete(blob.name).then((result) => {
           console.log(result);
           responseBody += result;
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });
   }
   ```

   1.2. To use `map` function for an Array object, as the figure below from the MDN document for [`Array object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Array_object).

   [image]

   ```
   listBlobsResult.entries.map((blob) => {
       azureStorage.delete(blob.name).then((result) => {
           console.log(result);
           responseBody += result;
       }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
       });
    });
   ```
2. According to the subsection [`List the blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs#list-the-blobs) of Azure offical document `How to upload, download, and list blobs using the client library for Node.js v2`, as the figure below, your `listAll` function using [`listBlobsSegmented(string, ContinuationToken, ErrorOrResult<ListBlobsResult>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-storage/azurestorage.services.blob.blobservice.blobservice?view=azure-node-latest#listblobssegmented-string--continuationtoken--errororresult-listblobsresult--) just list the first 5000 blobs in a container by passing `null` as the `ContinuationToken` parameter value, not list all blobs.

   [image]

   So to list all blobs if there is more 5000 blobs in a container, first to pass `null` to get the first 5000 blobs and `listBlobsResult.continuationToken`, then to pass the previous `listBlobsResult.continuationToken` value to function `listBlobsSegmented` to get the next 5000 blobs till the `listBlobsResult.continuationToken` value is null.

---

**Update: An implementation for `listAll`**

```
const listBlobs = async (continuationToken) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        blobService.listBlobsSegmented(containerName, continuationToken, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data)
            }
        });
    });
};

const listAll = async () => {
    first = await listBlobs(null);
    all = [].concat(first.entries)
    var continuationToken = first.continuationToken;
    while(continuationToken != null) {
        next = await listBlobs(continuationToken);
        all = all.concat(next.entries)
        continuationToken = next.continuationToken
    }
    return Promise.resolve(all);
};

(async() => {
    blobs = await listAll();
    blobs.map((result, index) => {console.log(index, result.name)})
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! I'll fix **listBlobsSegmented()** problem soon.

Comment: @yyp I post an implementation for `listAll`.

Answer (score -2):

There's an option called delimiter when listing blobs. Sample code:

```
blobService.listBlobsSegmentedWithPrefix('documents',null,null,{delimiter:'/'},(error,result,response)=>{
    console.log(result);
    console.log(response.body.EnumerationResults.Blobs.BlobPrefix);
})
```

With delimiter /, listing operation returns results of two parts.

- result, contains info of blobs under the root directory of container, e.g. file name
- BlobPrefix in response body, contains directory names of single level with delimiter.

```js
[ { Name: 'docx/' }, { Name: 'xlsx/' } ]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this solution too. This is quite a functional method makes me learn something more, but didn't solve my question directly. Thanks for answering!